# Can I use break statement in a method which can be later called from main where there is a while loop?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, break

For example, this could be checkGameStatus() method, checking if the game is over after every move.

```
       if((arr[0][0]=='X' && arr[0][1]=='X' && arr[0][2]=='X')||
       (arr[1][0]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[1][2]=='X')||
       (arr[2][0]=='X' && arr[2][1]=='X' && arr[2][2]=='X')||
       (arr[0][0]=='X' && arr[1][0]=='X' && arr[2][0]=='X')||
       (arr[0][1]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[2][1]=='X')||
       (arr[0][2]=='X' && arr[1][2]=='X' && arr[2][2]=='X')||
       (arr[0][0]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[2][2]=='X')||
       (arr[0][2]=='X' && arr[1][1]=='X' && arr[2][0]=='X')
       ){
           System.out.println("X wins!");
           break;
       }
    else if((arr[0][0]=='O' && arr[0][1]=='O' && arr[0][2]=='O')||
       (arr[1][0]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[1][2]=='O')||
       (arr[2][0]=='O' && arr[2][1]=='O' && arr[2][2]=='O')||
       (arr[0][0]=='O' && arr[1][0]=='O' && arr[2][0]=='O')||
       (arr[0][1]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[2][1]=='O')||
       (arr[0][2]=='O' && arr[1][2]=='O' && arr[2][2]=='O')||
       (arr[0][0]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[2][2]=='O')||
       (arr[0][2]=='O' && arr[1][1]=='O' && arr[2][0]=='O')
       ){
           System.out.println("O wins!");
           break;
       }
    else if(arr[0][0]!='_' && arr[0][1]!='_' && arr[0][2]!='_'
    && arr[1][0]!='_' && arr[1][1]!='_' && arr[1][2]!='_'
    && arr[2][0]!='_' && arr[2][1]!='_' && arr[2][2]!='_'){
        System.out.println("Draw!");
        break;
```

Path to the full program: [Tic-Tac-Toe for 2 players](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNXJZTGhYRVFTakk)

Comment: not different , else do this work

Comment: [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15) says: *A `break` statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement **of the immediately enclosing method** or initializer*. In other words, you cannot `break` out of a method. For that, you need an exception.

Comment: For that, you need an exception or return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'return' keyword is used to exit from a method, 'break' is not applicable for methods.

For your checkGameStatus(), you can try to return boolean and check it to break in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in Vegas stays in Vegas ...

What I mean by that: *break* statements are always "local" to "innermost" loop respectively switch that surrounds that *break* statement.

You do not need to worry about *breaks* in methods that you are invoking.

The only ways that calling a method can have effects on the caller would be things like changing the content of a field of the method (so changing the status of the surrounding object); or by changing the state of objects given to the method as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

"Break" has no effect on "If-Statements". "Break" is used with "switch", "for", "while" and "do".

If a condition is true, "System.out.println()" will be executed. The program then continues in the code after your "If-Statements".